# How to match a column across multiple columns and return matching col_name in a new column

Tags: r, match, tidyverse, across

Let's assume I have a dataset df wherein I want to match value of col `X` across values of multiple columns `A to F` and want to return the matching column name (else NA) in a new column.

dput

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(4L, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, 5L, NA, NA), 
    C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), D = c(NA, 4L, 6L, 7L), E = c(5L, NA, 
    NA, NA), F = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), X = 4:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

> df
   A  B  C  D  E  F X
1  4 NA NA NA  5 NA 4
2 NA  5 NA  4 NA NA 5
3 NA NA NA  6 NA NA 6
4 NA NA NA  7 NA NA 7
```

The output I want

```
> df_out
   A  B  C  D  E  F X new
1  4 NA NA NA  5 NA 4   A
2 NA  5 NA  4 NA NA 5   B
3 NA NA NA  6 NA NA 6   D
4 NA NA NA  7 NA NA 7   D
```

I will prefer `dplyr`/`tidyverse` syntax that I'll integrate into my existing syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(new = names(.)[which(c_across(-X) %in% X)])

      A     B C         D     E F         X new  
  <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <chr>
1     4    NA NA       NA     5 NA        4 A    
2    NA     5 NA        4    NA NA        5 B    
3    NA    NA NA        6    NA NA        6 D    
4    NA    NA NA        7    NA NA        7 D
```

The solution above assumes that the column names correspond to the positions established by `which()`. However, if it is not the case (e.g. `c_across(-c(C, E, X)`), then the results won't be correct. A solution for more complex situations could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(new = Reduce(coalesce, across(-c(C, E, X), ~ ifelse(. == X, cur_column(), NA_character_))))
                          
   A  B  C  D  E  F X new
1  4 NA NA NA  5 NA 4   A
2 NA  5 NA  4 NA NA 5   B
3 NA NA NA  6 NA NA 6   D
4 NA NA NA  7 NA NA 7   D
```

Comment: In reality I have many columns to check and to exclude.  But the column names for match (A:F here) follow a pattern.  So how can I use `contains("pattern")` here?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, `c_across()` allows to use the standard select helpers, such as `c_across(-starts_with("X"))`.

Comment: still not working in my case.  Actually, in my case there are strings instead of integers to match.  Is it the problem?

Comment: No, as far as I can tell, that shouldn't be a problem. However, it is a good practice to include a realistic sample dataset, so that solutions could be tailored accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -X) %>%
  mutate(
    match = if_else(X == value, name, NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  filter(!is.na(match))
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I feel this will take more time because it'll pivot two times

Answer (score 2):

Compare `A:F` column with `X` column, replace `NA`'s with `FALSE` and use `max.col` to get the index of `TRUE` value in each row which can be used to get column name.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new = {
    tmp <- select(., A:F) == X
    names(.)[max.col(replace(tmp, is.na(tmp), FALSE))]
  })

#   A  B  C  D  E  F X new
#1  4 NA NA NA  5 NA 4   A
#2 NA  5 NA  4 NA NA 5   B
#3 NA NA NA  6 NA NA 6   D
#4 NA NA NA  7 NA NA 7   D
```

In base R this can be written as :

```
tmp <- df[1:5] == df$X
df$new <- names(df)[max.col(replace(tmp, is.na(tmp), FALSE))]
```

This solution assumes that you'll have at least one match of `X` in the row as shown in the example.